# Can I return an array with foreach loop?

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

So I tried to return my array with a foreach loop... but no results... If someone can help me return an array, it will help me greatly.
Here is the test code of how I tried to do that:

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach(int i in ints)
{
    return ints[i];
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to return an array in a loop?

Comment: you cannot do that with an array, but with an `IEnumerable<int>` for instance, by wrizing `yield return ints[i];`. However why not simply return the array directly, you don't need a loop at all.

Comment: What do you think happens in that loop?  Your code sets up to iterate over the array `{ 1, 2, 3 }`.  Then it pulls out the first item (`1`), and starts running the code in the block. That code says `return ints[i];`.  So, `ints[1]` is evaluated.  That's `2` (since array indexing starts at 0).  Your code should be returning `2`.  Is it not doing that?  That's the _result_ I'd expect

Comment: Why not just skip the loop entirely and use `return ints;` ?  What's the goal here?

Comment: Since the asker doesn't seem interested in stating what they are trying to do, let's just get the question closed instead of guessing their intention and coming up with answers that won't help anyway.

Comment: And why is someone upvoting a completely unclear question as this?

Comment: I tried to do this in a method with ref.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @lee Taylor mentioned. It is weird to do this, but [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) is what you want.

```
int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach(int i in ints)
{
    yield return i;
}
```

Comment: Probably should be `yield return i;`

Comment: In C#, `i` is **not** the index. It's the value. Change the items in the array and this will be obvious.

Comment: This will crash when it reaches `i == 3` because `ints[3]` will throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: (Note: This has now been edited to be correct)

Comment: Because it's the accepted answer, I didn't want to leave the bad code showing.

Comment: NP, I was just letting future readers know in case the comments confused them! :)

Comment: This could only make sense in a method declare as returning `IEnumerable<int>`, and then of course replacing the whole thing with `return ints` is also legal -- and shorter. If anything interesting was done with `i` it would be another matter.

Comment: The code shown in this answer will (to the caller) appear to be the same as just saying:  `int[] ints = { 1, 2, 3 }; return ints;`.  Yes, one returns a fully materialized `IEnumerable<int>` (i.e., the array), while the other doesn't.  This code will not, as the question asks _"return an array"_. It returns an `IEnumerable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question shows how javascript handles `foreach` loops. In javascript, the `foreach` loop iterates over the **indexes**. C# is different. In C#, the `foreach` loop iterates over the **values**. Therefore you want this:

```
int[] ints = { 4, 5, 6 };

foreach(int i in ints)
{
    return i;
}
```

Additionally, this code will **exit the method** as soon as it hits the `return` keyword for the first time and only provide the first value. If you want to return an array, you can just... return the array:

```
int[] ints = { 4, 5, 6 };
return ints;
```